# Anaconda not working after Catalina Installation (accessing Jupyter notebooks)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I recently upgraded to MacOS Catalina to take advantage of various new features/improvements. Soon after installation, I noticed that a question grey mark appeared over the Anaconda icon in my applications. Additionally, my Anaconda files have seemingly been migrated to the "[Relocated Items](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/a-relocated-items-folder-upgrading-macos-x-mchl8ae423a3/mac)" folder now on my desktop.

I am not sure exactly how to deal with this. I have tried clicking the Anaconda icon with the question mark to launch it, but this fails. I have also attempted locating my Jupyter notebooks in the relocated items file but have not been able to do so successfully.

My question is what do I need to do to fix this problem to restore normal functionality back? Do I need to reinstall Anaconda? Will this new installation have my old Jupyter notebooks?

From a little reading online I have found that Apple says that no files should be deleted; therefore, in theory, there should be no loss of data from the upgrade. I am just not sure how I can restore access to these Jupyter notebooks.

Not sure if anyone else has experienced a similar problem. Any help or general guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda not found after upgrading to macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291108/conda-not-found-after-upgrading-to-macos-catalina). Also, [Anaconda published a blog post about this](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/).

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, and the linked articles definitely are relevant, however I am very novice when it comes to terminal, roots, user etc. (why I code Python in Jupyter) therefore, many of these solutions are fairly abstruse.

Comment: Simple explanation, Catalina improves security by making some areas of the file system inaccessible. Software that used to use these areas have those files moved to "Relocated Items" instead of deleting them, it's assumed that if you can't figure out where to put them so they work, whoever created the software that put them there can tell you. Or maybe they'll make an installer or updater that can fix that.

Comment: One thing you can try is uninstall the problem software, and install a new version that's compatible with Catalina. If that works, you can delete the unneeded files in "Removed Items" - if you're sure they're really not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: As I just found out, Anaconda rolled out a new update to address this issue. I went to their website [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and just downloaded a fresh installation of the latest version of Anaconda. This worked great and completely fixed the issue. I can now access all of my pervious Jupyter notebooks.